# Heroku Postgres throwing int out of range error for ints that should be in range

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to collect options data using a heroku dyno (hobby $7 version) and a heroku Postgres database (standard $50 version). I've got a small script set up that uses yfinance to collect options data for a set of ticker symbols and SQLAlchemy + psycopg2 to insert this data into the postgres database.

I seem to be encountering a very strange error when inserting into the database. For many of the records, I'm seeing a `(psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) integer out of range` Exception thrown for records that should not have any integers out of range... I've included an example of the error below as well as my model definition. At first I thought maybe it was the id / pk column, but according to [SQLAlchemy's docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html) they automatically treat these fields as a serial data type. So I'm not sure why this error is being thrown with all integer columns clearly [in the range of the INT data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html).

Is this a heroku thing? Has anyone seen / dealt with this before? I'm not sure how to debug the underlying issue. Thanks in advance!

```
2021-03-24 12:25:16 ERROR    Unable to commit Option(id=None, ticker=EDIT, option_type=PUT, contractSymbol=EDIT230120P00017500, lastTradeDate=2020-11-05 14:38:12, strike=17.5, lastPrice=4.7, bid=0.0, ask=0.0, change=0.0, percentChange=0.0, volume=1.0, openInterest=0, impliedVolatility=0.12500875, inTheMoney=False, contractSize=REGULAR, currency=USD)
2021-03-24 12:25:16 ERROR    This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) integer out of range

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/7s2a)
Continuing.
```

Model definition:

```
class Option(config.Base):

    __tablename__ = "options"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ticker = Column(String, nullable=False)
    dt_created_db = Column(
        DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    )
    dt_updated_db = Column(
        DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    )
    dt_created_market_time_db = Column(
        DateTime, nullable=False,
        default=datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(
            pytz.timezone(
                "America/New_York"
            )
        )
    )
    option_type = Column(String, nullable=False) # CALL or PUT
    contractSymbol = Column(String, nullable=False)
    lastTradeDate = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    strike = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    lastPrice = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    bid = Column(Float)
    ask = Column(Float)
    change = Column(Float)
    percentChange = Column(Float)
    volume = Column(Float)
    openInterest = Column(Integer)
    impliedVolatility = Column(Numeric)
    inTheMoney = Column(Boolean)
    contractSize = Column(String)
    currency = Column(String)

    @classmethod
    def create_option_record(cls, ticker, record, opt_type):
        """Creates an Option model instance.

        Args:
            ticker: The ticker symbol.
            record: A pandas dataframe row with "." access to columns.
            opt_type: A string, either CALL or PUT.
        Returns:
            Option object.
        """
        return cls(
            ticker=ticker,
            option_type=opt_type,
            contractSymbol=record.contractSymbol,
            lastTradeDate=record.lastTradeDate,
            strike=record.strike,
            lastPrice=record.lastPrice,
            bid=record.bid,
            ask=record.ask,
            change=record.change,
            percentChange=record.percentChange,
            volume=record.volume,
            openInterest=record.openInterest,
            impliedVolatility=round(record.impliedVolatility, 20),
            inTheMoney=record.inTheMoney,
            contractSize=record.contractSize,
            currency=record.currency
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"Option("
            f"id={self.id}, "
            f"ticker={self.ticker}, "
            f"option_type={self.option_type}, "
            f"contractSymbol={self.contractSymbol}, "
            f"lastTradeDate={self.lastTradeDate}, "
            f"strike={self.strike}, "
            f"lastPrice={self.lastPrice}, "
            f"bid={self.bid}, "
            f"ask={self.ask}, "
            f"change={self.change}, "
            f"percentChange={self.percentChange}, "
            f"volume={self.volume}, "
            f"openInterest={self.openInterest}, "
            f"impliedVolatility={self.impliedVolatility}, "
            f"inTheMoney={self.inTheMoney}, "
            f"contractSize={self.contractSize}, "
            f"currency={self.currency}"
            f")"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this. It turns out the database logs were behind the compute logs and so the record I thought was causing the error was not actually causing the error.

The root cause was that an `np.nan` value was being inserted into an `INTEGER` column. I had to replace `np.nan`'s with `None` and this solved the problem.